# Semicolon usage in Promela

Tags: if-statement, syntax, promela, spin

I am learning promela syntax for Spin Modal Checker. I encountered this simple piece of code.

```
int count;
active proctype count(){
if
::   count++
::   count--
fi
}
```

As I know semicolon is used to define end of statement. Can I use `;` in the end of both `count++` and `count--` and after `fi`; Will it change the way program is behaving? I would be grateful for clearing this semicolon thing for me.

Comment: Even though `;` is a separator rather than a terminator, I think it is a good habit to use it as a terminator, as it often happens that people decide at some point to append new lines of code somewhere in the source but forget to add the semicolon on the previous line, resulting in a compilation error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Semicolons in Promela are so-called *separators*.

From [the reference](http://spinroot.com/spin/Man/separators.html):

> The semicolon and the arrow are equivalent statement *separators* in Promela; they are not statement *terminators*, although the parser has been taught to be forgiving for occasional lapses. The last statement in a sequence need not be followed by a statement separator, unlike, for instance, in the C programming language.

So the answer to your question is: you don't need to put semicolons after `count++`, `count--`, or `fi` because they are the last statements. The parser will ignore if you put them there anyway.